# PHP prevent double clean url (improvements?)

Tags: php, recursion, clean-urls

For a client at work we have build a website.The website has an offering page which can contain variants of the same type/build, so they ran into problems with double clean-urls.

Just now I wrote a function to prevent that from happening by appending a number to the URL. If thatclean url also exists it counts up.

E.g.

domain.nl/product/machine

domain.nl/product/machine-1

domain.nl/product/machine-2

Updated! return $clean_url; on recursion and on return

The function I wrote works fine, but I was wondering if I have taken the right approach and if it maybe could be improved. Here's the code:

```
public function prevent_double_cleanurl($cleanurl)
{

    // makes sure it doesnt check against itself
            if($this->ID!=NULL) $and = " AND product_ID <> ".$this->ID;

    $sql = "SELECT product_ID, titel_url FROM " . $this->_table . " WHERE titel_url='".$cleanurl."' " . $and. " LIMIT 1";

    $result = $this->query($sql);

            // if a matching url is found
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $url_parts = explode("-", $result[0]['titel_url']);
        $last_part = end($url_parts);

        // maximum of 2 digits
        if((int)$last_part && strlen($last_part)<3)
        {
            // if a 1 or 2 digit number is found - add to it
                            array_pop($url_parts);
            $cleanurl = implode("-", $url_parts);

            (int)$last_part++;
        }
        else
        {
            // add a suffix starting at 1
                            $last_part='1';
        }
                    // recursive check
        $cleanurl = $this->prevent_double_cleanurl($cleanurl.'-'.$last_part);
    }

    return $cleanurl; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works fine?  Where is `$titel_url` that you return set?

Comment: You were totally right. I did update it in the project, ran into the same problem. I've updated the code above too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the likeliness of a "clean-url" being used multiple times, your approach may not be the best to roll with. Say there was "foo" to "foo-10" you'd be calling the database 10 times.

you also don't seem to sanitize the data you shove into your SQL queries. Are you using [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (or its mysqli, PDO, whatever brother)?

Revised code:

```
public function prevent_double_cleanurl($cleanurl) {
    $cleanurl_pattern = '#^(?<base>.*?)(-(?<num>\d+))?$#S';

    if (preg_match($cleanurl_pattern, $base, $matches)) {
        $base = $matches['base'];
        $num = $matches['num'] ? $matches['num'] : 0;
    } else {
        $base = $cleanurl;
        $num = 0;
    }
    
    // makes sure it doesnt check against itself
    if ($this->ID != null) {
        $and = " AND product_ID <> " . $this->ID;
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT product_ID, titel_url FROM " . $this->_table . " WHERE titel_url LIKE '" . $base . "-%' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->query($sql);
    
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if ($this->ID && $row['product_ID'] == $this->ID) {
            // the given cleanurl already has an ID,
            // so we better not touch it
            return $cleanurl;
        }
        
        if (preg_match($cleanurl_pattern, $row['titel_url'], $matches)) {
            $_base = $matches['base'];
            $_num = $matches['num'] ? $matches['num'] : 0;
        } else {
            $_base = $row['titel_url'];
            $_num = 0;
        }
        
        if ($base != $_base) {
            // make sure we're not accidentally comparing "foo-123" and "foo-bar-123"
            continue;
        }
        
        if ($_num > $num) {
            $num = $_num;
        }
    }
    
    // next free number
    $num++;
    return $base . '-' . $num;
}
```

I don't know about the possible values for your clean-urls. Last time I did something like this, my base could look like `some-article-revision-5`. That `5` being part of the actual bullet, not the duplication-index. To distinguish them (and allow the `LIKE` to filter out false positives) I made the clean-urls look like `$base--$num`. the double dash could only occur between the base and the duplication-index, making things a bit simpler…

Comment: Its close to what I suggested, except it wouldn't work for two reasons.  **1)** `MAX(<string>)` will sort lexicographically, not numerically and since he doesn't zero pad it will return the wrong result for > 9 entries.  **2)** `foo-%` will match entries that have been rewritten, but it will not match the original non-rewritten base URL because of the hyphen.

Comment: I fixed my example to not use MAX() [duh, could've thought of that myself…] and a false-positive-check for `foo-%`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to test this, so its on you, but here's how I'd do it.  I put a ton of comments in there explaining my reasoning and the flow of the code.

Basically, the recursion is unnecessary will result in more database queries than you need.

```
<?
public function prevent_double_cleanurl($cleanurl)
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT product_ID, titel_url FROM %s WHERE titel_url LIKE '%s%%'", 
        $this->_table, $cleanurl);
    if($this->ID != NULL){ $sql.= sprintf(" AND product_ID <> %d", $this->ID); }

    $results = $this->query($sql);

    $suffix = 0;
    $baseurl = true;
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        // Consider the case when we get to the "first" row added to the db:
        //  For example: $row['titel_url'] == $cleanurl == 'domain.nl/product/machine'
        if($row['title_url'] == $cleanurl)
        {
            $baseurl = false;   // The $cleanurl is already in the db, "this" is not a base URL
            continue;           // Continue with the next iteration of the foreach loop
        }

        // This could be done using regex, but if this works its fine.
        // Make sure to test for the case when you have both of the following pages in your db:
        //
        //  some-hyphenated-page
        //  some-hyphenated-page-name
        //
        // You don't want the counters to get mixed up
        $url_parts = explode("-", $row['titel_url']);
        $last_part = array_pop($url_parts);
        $cleanrow = implode("-", $url_parts);

        // To get into this block, three things need to be true
        //  1. $last_part must be a numeric string (PHP Duck Typing bleh)
        //  2. When represented as a string, $last_part must not be longer than 2 digits
        //  3. The string passed to this function must match the string resulting from the (n-1) 
        //      leading parts of the result of exploding the table row
        if((is_numeric($last_part)) && (strlen($last_part)<=2) && ($cleanrow == $cleanurl))
        {
            $baseurl = false;                           // If there are records in the database, the 
                                                        //  passed $cleanurl isn't the first, so it 
                                                        //  will need a suffix
            $suffix = max($suffix, (int)$last_part);    // After this foreach loop is done, $suffix 
                                                        //  will contain the highest suffix in the 
                                                        //  database we'll need to add 1 to this to 
                                                        //  get the result url
        }
    }

    // If $baseurl is still true, then we never got into the 3-condition block above, so we never 
    //  a matching record in the database -> return the cleanurl that was passed here, no need
    //  to add a suffix
    if($baseurl)
    {
        return $cleanurl;
    }
    // At least one database record exists, so we need to add a suffix.  The suffix we add will be
    //  the higgest we found in the database plus 1.
    else
    {
        return sprintf("%s-%d", $cleanurl, ($suffix + 1));
    }
}
```

My solution takes advantage of SQL wildcards (`%`) to reduce the number of queries from *n* down to 1.

Make sure that you ensure problematic case I described in lines 14-20 works as expected.  Hyphens in the machine name (or whatever it is) could do unexpected things.

I also used `sprintf` to format the query.  Make sure you sanitize any string that is passed through as a string (e.g. `$cleanurl`).

As @rodneyrehm points out, PHP is very flexible with what it considers a numeric string.  You might consider switching out [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) for [`ctype_digit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) and see how that works.

Comment: PS, I use 100 columns on my text editors now-a-days, sorry that there is overflow, stackoverflow limits the code boxes to around 85.

Comment: `(is_int($last_part))` will always be false here. `$last_part` is an element of the result array of `explode()` - they're all strings. You're probably looking for `is_numeric()`, but should note that `is_numeric("3e3") == true`. so you'd probably want to do that with a regex

Comment: You're right, I read the note too quickly.  PHP's duck typing drives me insane.  PS `"0xFF" == 255 => TRUE` in PHP land